# Mobile Device MAc Address

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

I have a windows mobile project.I want to get the MAC address or numbers of the device for securitiy of my software. My project is in Windows Ce and Windows Mobile 6 (two project). How can I get the value from the mobile device? (I looked the same questions but they are about Bluetooth MAC address and some devices don't have it)

Answer (score 2):

Call the [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450394.aspx) API.  It returns an [`IP_ADAPTER_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891170.aspx) which is a buffer of all infos for the device's adapters.  The `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` contains a member called `Address` which is the adapter's MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Since I take a lot time to find a VB.NET way to this,so I post this for anyone that could be useful.

```
<DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GetAdaptersInfo(ByVal info As Byte(), ByRef size As UInteger) As Integer
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetMacAddress() As String
            Dim num As UInteger = 0UI
            GetAdaptersInfo(Nothing, num)
            Dim array As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(num) - 1) {}
            Dim adaptersInfo As Integer = GetAdaptersInfo(array, num)
            If adaptersInfo = 0 Then
                Dim macAddress As String = ""
                Dim macLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 400)
                macAddress = BitConverter.ToString(array, 404, macLength)
                macAddress = macAddress.Replace("-", ":")

                Return macAddress
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
```